# Having text data stored in pandas frame, how to implement simple classification with sklearn

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, classification

I have a frame that stores text reviews in column A and ratings (1 to 5) in column B.

```
id .....review ..............rating          
1  .....That was awful ......1...
```

I need to create a simple (any algorithm-based) classifier, for example, based on features like word:occurrances vocabulary, that would predict if rating > 3 or < 3 (let's say we'd add another col with 1 if rating > 3 and 0 if <)

I'm not good at Python and machine learning, so I got stuck on all samples I've googled.

Please, explain, how to extract features in that sample case, how to train a model and so on, or provide a good tutor for that case (I'm not able to translate sklearn tutor to my case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this extremely easily in scikit.

Let's say you have X and y data:

```
X = ['the food was really delicious', 'the food was really terrible']
y = [5,2]
```

Using `CountVectorizer` you can convert the data into numbers in 2 lines of code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
x_data = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(X)
```

This fully converts your data into counts, and can then feed into whichever algorithm you want:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighbors
clf = KNeighbors().fit(x_data, y)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use CountVectorizer, but obviously failed to understand its attributes and syntax :-(
This is really good to see your answer after I succeeded with clues given me by the User below!

Answer (score 2):

There are about two general steps, which could be explained in great detail.

#### Feature Extraction

First, you need to determine which features to use. This is one of the main tasks, and is up to you. The standard approach is a [bag-of-words model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model). This counts the occurrence of each word in each text. [It is](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#applications-and-examples)

> quite simplistic but surprisingly useful in practice

There are also specialized tools that do a tf-idf analysis for you, for example [Sally](http://www.mlsec.org/sally/).

Let's assume you want to do this in Python using scikit-learn. The data is already available as a `class Review(object)` with `text` and `rating` attributes. From the `text`, you need to extract features.

Example:

```
def extract(review):
    '''extracts features from review'''
    result = {}
    for word in review.text.split():
        if result[word] is not None:
            result[word] += 1
        else:
            result[word] = 1
    return result
```

would give you a count of all words in text (there is also a library class `Counter`, which might do that for you). These, you could combine to form a feature matrix `X`. (This code could be heavily optimized)

```
X = []
y = []
words = []
# build an index of all occurring words
for review in reviews:
    for word in extract(review):
        if word not in words:
            words.append(word)
# creates the feature vectors for classification
for review in reviews:
    feature_vector = [0] * len(words)
    y.append(review.rating)
    for word, count in extract(review):
        feature_vector[words.index(word)] = count
    X.append(feature_vector)
```

#### Classification

Now you have got the feature vector, you need to decide which classifier to use. Among the easiest is [k-nearest-neighbors](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html).

```
from sklearn import neighbors, cross_validation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
knn = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
knn.predict(X_test)
```

Compare this to `y_test`.

#### Example from comments (slightly edited)

> Let's consider an example of two reviews:
>
> 1. that was awful | rating 1;
> 2. that was great | rating 5.
>
> Two dicts are created: `{'that': 1, 'was': 1, 'awful': 1 }` and `{'that': 1, 'was': 1, 'great': 1}`. And what X and y vectors should look like in that case?

Firstly, your `words` might be `['that', 'was', 'awful', 'great']`.

Then, you might get

```
X = [[1, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 1]]
y = [1, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my entry and the answer. Still, i'm not sure i understood everything. Considering the first block of code, do i get it right - i should create a separate dictionary for each review with this code and place it in separate column, or something else? I understand how to rewrite this code to make a function that takes a string and returns a dictionary, but in that case i don't understand what it does - does it take a whole frame to return dict?

Comment: And coming to the second block of code where we are creating features vector, it would be easy for me to understand what to do if i would know what should this vector look like. Let's consider an example of two reviews: 1) that was awful | rating 1; 2) that was great | rating 5. Two dicts are created: {that: 1, was: 1, awful: 1 } and {that: 1, was: 1, great: 1}. And what X and y vectors should look like in that case? Sorry if i'm too noobie here :-(

Comment: @SergeiHudozhnin: I used a `Frame` for a single `review`. But yes, you got it right. One dict for each review. That is placed in a separate *row*, but you got the main point. This function is called once for each `review`, no need for panda frames. See the edit concerning the second comment.